# JSF / PrimeFaces selecting two rows from two p:dataTables arranged in a master-detail fashion fails with Request Scope

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I stumbled upon a **JSF** / **PrimeFaces** problem and although I managed to get it working by changing the scope of the backing bean I would still like to understand why it failed in the first case. So, here's a narrowed-down example that reproduces the behavior:

We have a dead simple **xhtml** page that displays two **p:dataTables** in a form, one below the other. The top **p:dataTable** displays numbers and the second their divisors. So we have a classical master-detail view. A button allows us to update the page so when a new number is selected from the top table we can view its divisors on the bottom table:

```
<h:form id="NUMBERS-form">
    <p:dataTable id="dt1" var="item" value="#{numbersController.divisorSets}"
                 rowKey="#{item}" rows="10" selection="#{numbersController.selectedDivisorSet}"
                 selectionMode="single">
        <p:column>
            #{item}
        </p:column>
    </p:dataTable>

    <p:dataTable id="dt2" var="item" value="#{numbersController.divisors}"
                 rowKey="#{item}" rows="10" selection="#{numbersController.selectedDivisor}"
                 selectionMode="single">
        <p:column id>
            #{item}
        </p:column>
    </p:dataTable>
    <p:commandButton id="Update"     ajax="true" update=":NUMBERS-form"
                     action="#{numbersController.foo}" value="update"/>
</h:form>
```

The backing bean defines two read-only collections: one for the *DivisorSets* (i.e. the numbers whose divisors we want to find) and another one for the divisors of currently selected number. It also has two fields and property getters/setters for the currently selected number and the currently selected divisor of that number:

```
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped // if this is toggled to @RequestScoped it stops working
public class NumbersController implements Serializable {
    private static final Logger l = Logger.getLogger(NumbersController.class.getName());

    public List<DivisorSet> getDivisorSets() {
        List<DivisorSet> retValue = new ArrayList<DivisorSet>();
        for (int i = 10 ; i < 20 ; i++)
            retValue.add( new DivisorSet(i) );
        return retValue;
    }

    public List<Integer> getDivisors() {
        if (selectedDivisorSet != null)
            return selectedDivisorSet.getDivisors();
        else return null;
    }

    private DivisorSet    selectedDivisorSet;
    // getter and setter ...

    private Integer   selectedDivisor;
    // getter and setter ...

    public String foo() { return null; }
}
```

When the page first loads, only the top **p:dataTable** is populated. When a row of the top table is selected and the **p:commandButton** pressed, the divisors of that number are fetched on the bottom **p:dataTable**. So far so good. Here comes the problem: when a row is selected from the top table and a row also selected from the bottom table and the **p:commandButton** pressed, the logging messages I have in the setters reveal that:

1. when the scope of the backing bean is set to **View** both selected numbers are set correctly in the **update model values** phase
2. when the scope of the backing bean is set to **Request** only the selected number from the top table is set correctly, the setter for the **selectedDivisor** field (that is linked with the bottom **p:dataTable**) carries a value of 0 (or null in other examples I've tried with different classes used).

Note that there is no business logic in this trivial example to make it necessary to select a number from the bottom **p:dataTable** - this is just a narrowed-down version of the same problem I had in a real context. Can anybody explain the steps in the JSF lifecycle that result in the bottom table selected value not set properly when view is **RequestScoped** (as opposed to **ViewScoped** that succeeds)?

Comment: Why do you expect it to work in request scope?

Comment: Please note that it does work in both scopes so far as its simple functionality is concerned. What doesn't work at RequestScope is that the setter method for the 'selectedDivisor' field (that's linked to the bottom table) is called with a value of 0 instead of the value of the actually selected row. Although that doesn't cause any problems in this simple page, that's the part I don't get: i.e. why the setter method for the 'selectedDivisorSet' field (that's linked to the top table) is called with the right value, whereas the setter for the 'selectedDivisor' field is called with a value of 0.